# Getting an error while using JAVE library in an Android project

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm using an external library called [JAVE](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/index.php) in my Android project in order to extract the audio from a video file.

My code:

```
 public void extractAudio() {
    File source = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/test.flv");
    File target = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/test.mp3");
    AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
    audio.setCodec("libmp3lame");
    audio.setBitRate(new Integer(128000));
    audio.setChannels(new Integer(2));
    audio.setSamplingRate(new Integer(44100));
    EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
    attrs.setFormat("mp3");
    attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);
    Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
    try {
        encoder.encode(source, target, attrs);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InputFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (EncoderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

These are the errors I get:

```
11-09 18:26:49.874: W/System.err(6594): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/bin/chmod, 755, /sdcard/jave-1/ffmpeg] Working Directory: null Environment: null
11-09 18:26:49.874: W/System.err(6594):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
11-09 18:26:49.874: W/System.err(6594):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:168)
11-09 18:26:49.884: W/System.err(6594):     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:123)
11-09 18:26:49.884: W/System.err(6594):     at it.sauronsoftware.jave.DefaultFFMPEGLocator.<init>(DefaultFFMPEGLocator.java:85)
11-09 18:26:49.884: W/System.err(6594):     at it.sauronsoftware.jave.Encoder.<init>(Encoder.java:111)
11-09 18:26:49.884: W/System.err(6594):     at com.yt.ringtones.RipActivity.extractAudio(RipActivity.java:236)
11-09 18:26:49.894: W/System.err(6594):     at com.yt.ringtones.RipActivity$1$DownloadFromUrl.onPostExecute(RipActivity.java:94)
11-09 18:26:49.894: W/System.err(6594):     at com.yt.ringtones.RipActivity$1$DownloadFromUrl.onPostExecute(RipActivity.java:1)
11-09 18:26:49.894: W/System.err(6594):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
11-09 18:26:49.894: W/System.err(6594):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
11-09 18:26:49.986: W/System.err(6594):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
11-09 18:26:49.986: W/System.err(6594):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-09 18:26:49.986: W/System.err(6594):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-09 18:26:49.994: W/System.err(6594):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-09 18:26:49.994: W/System.err(6594):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 18:26:49.994: W/System.err(6594):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-09 18:26:50.014: W/System.err(6594):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-09 18:26:50.014: W/System.err(6594):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-09 18:26:50.024: W/System.err(6594):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-09 18:26:50.024: W/System.err(6594): Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
11-09 18:26:50.024: W/System.err(6594):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
11-09 18:26:50.034: W/System.err(6594):     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
```

I'm rather new to Android development and I'm not really sure what's the problem here. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you upload a full stack trace?

Comment: So in your previous stack trace you had "exec(). Command: [/sdcard/jave-1/ffmpeg..." and now it is "exec(). Command: [/bin/chmod..." Are you sure this is the correct stack trace?

Comment: I'm not sure why it changed now. The logcat says there are "... 18 more" but I'm not sure how to access them.

Comment: @Archer2486 can you please help me out how you have added this library in your android project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"exec()" basically executes a command in a system, as if you would run it from a command line. It is trying to run "/sdcard/jave-1/ffmpeg", which is supposed to be an executable file. Do you have this executable on your device? If not, this will not work.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The "/sdcard/jave-1/ffmpeg" does exist. I've added the rest of the stack trace to the original message.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that there is another error in the stack trace: "W/System.err(6594): Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory" I suspect this might be because of "Working Directory: null" in the top error message. Can you try setting the working directory?

Comment: @AntonCherkashyn can you please help me out how can i add jave lib in my android project?

Comment: from where can i get "jave-1/ffmpeg"?

Answer (score 0):

This errors happens due to wrong ffmpeg file permissions. Here is my answer in similar thread: [Using sauronsoftware's Jave in phonegap Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863155/using-sauronsoftwares-jave-in-phonegap-android-project/30482674#30482674)