# Using sauronsoftware's Jave in phonegap Android project

Tags: android, cordova, ffmpeg

I'm developing phonegap app and right now  I'm trying to write a plugin to convert .amr files to .mp3 files. I'm using [JAVE](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/%20%22JAVE) to do this conversion and while it's working on desktop it fails on android with this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). 
Command: [/data/data/<my_package>/cache/jave-1/ffmpeg, -i, /sdcard/<my_filename>.amr, -vn, -acodec, libmp3lame, -f, mp3, -y, /sdcard/<my_filename>.mp3] 
Working Directory: null Enviroment: null
```

I'm trying to do conversion like this:

```
private void convert(String input_file, CallbackContext callbackContext){
  File input = new File(input_file);
  File output = new File(input_file.replace(".amr", ".mp3"));

  Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
  EncodingAttributes encodingAttributes = new EncodingAttributes();
  AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes();
  audioAttributes.setCodec("libmp3lame");
  encodingAttributes.setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes);
  encodingAttributes.setFormat("mp3");

  try{
    encoder.encode(input, output, encodingAttributes);
    input.delete();
    callbackContext.success("finished");
  }
  catch(Exception e){
     callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312194/getting-an-error-while-using-jave-library-in-an-android-project) and I understand why error happens but the answer doesn't provide any solution. Is there a way to get this working in Phonegap project? Do I need to package ffmpeg library together with plugin and copy it to correct folder when app invokes the plugin?

```
/data/data/<my_package>/cache/jave-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Stucked with same problem. For now i found that there is problem with file ffmpeg permissions. JAVE trying to set them, but for some reason it not working.
So i set this permission by myself like this:

```
    Process process = null;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("chmod 0755 __AppCachePath__/jave-1/ffmpeg\n");
        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("exit\n");
        dataOutputStream.flush();
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    } finally {
        try {
            if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                dataOutputStream.close();
            }
            process.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

After this File permission problem goes away.

Comment: how can i executable of ffmpeg?